# Extend python function to handle sympy symbols

Tags: python, sympy

Given an existing function which was written for numerical values, does Sympy have a suggested approach for extending it handle symbols?  For example:

```
import numpy as np
def foo(ax, ay, az):
  A = np.matrix([[1. ,    ax,          0],
                 [0  , 1./ay,          0],
                 [0  ,     0, np.cos(az)]])
  return A
foo(1, 2, 3)

# We want this to work too:
import sympy as spy
ax, ay, az = spy.symbols(('ax', 'ay', 'az'))
foo(ax, ay, az)
```

How should one extend `foo()` to handle sympy symbols `ax, ay, az` and therefore return a symbolic matrix `A`?  Does sympy have any utilities to assist with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately you can't handle sympy symbols in a numpy function. A dirty solution would be to check the type of the variable and decide which function to use.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as spy

def foo(ax, ay, az):
  A = np.matrix([[1.,    ax, 0                                                    ],
                 [0 , 1./ay, 0                                                    ],
                 [0 , 0    , spy.cos(az) if type(az) is spy.Symbol else np.cos(az)]])
  return A

print foo(1, 2, 3)

ax, ay, az = spy.symbols(('ax', 'ay', 'az'))
print foo(ax, ay, az)
>>>
[[ 1.         1.         0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.5        0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.        -0.9899925]]
[[1.0 ax 0]
 [0 1.0/ay 0]
 [0 0 cos(az)]]
```

Comment: If there is a more elegant solution, I'd still be interested.  Seems like it might be a common task - one has an existing function and wants to extend it to work with Sympy.